# Django error (1054, "Unknown column 'models_author.user' in 'field list'")

Tags: python, mysql, django

In models.py I changed the name of the field "login" to "user" and added others.

Even having executed: Python3 manage.py makemigrations models, python3
manage.py sqlmigrate models 0001 and python3 manage.py migrate.
I still get an error

> (1054, "Unknown column 'models_author.user' in 'field list'")`.

If I change the field back to "login" it works perfectly.
Versions Python 3.5.2 django.VERSION (2, 2, 6, "final", 0)
the database is in MYSQL.

Code:Models.py

```
class Autor(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    usuario=models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', )
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comentario = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: thanks for sharing the status report.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's much better if you share your non-working code as a minimal reproducible example so that the proposed solution actually applies to your problem and can help future visitors with the same problem. Otherwise, there's a high likelihood that people will be tossing out random solutions that might not help you (or anyone else) much. See How to Ask and take the tour for more information on how to ask an on-topic question

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: I followed the guidelines to ask questions, but I didn't get it and I had to publish it as I could. It is more difficult to publish well than to solve the doubt.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a new field in the Django model and after deploying to any environment , you are getting error while accessing the field. Error: "1054, Unknown column"

Although i also was not able to figure out how to resolve it but i came up with a work around.

I created a column manually in the DB .
I added the same field in the model.
Again tried to access the field and it worked like a charm.
I hope it helps your case.